# This String Variable Always Gives Me Zero When Inserted In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP function :

```
public function addInvoice ($order_id, $invoice_id, $product_id, $product_quantity, $product_price, $product_reseller_fee, 
                            $product_reseller_poin, $product_referral_fee, $product_referral_id, 
                            $product_vendor_sales, $custom_invoice){

    $this->connect();

    $this->select('shopping_cart', 'courier_cost', NULL, 'product_id = "'.$product_id.'" AND order_id = "'.$order_id.'"', NULL, '1');
    $ongkir = $this->getResult();
    $ongkir = $ongkir[0]['courier_cost'];           //-- this gives me ZERO when inserted into MySQL
    $product_vendor_income = ($product_vendor_sales * $product_quantity) + $ongkir;     //-- $ongkir in this formula also count as ZERO

    $data = array ('order_id' => $this->escapeString($order_id),
                   'invoice_id' => $this->escapeString($invoice_id),
                   'product_id' => $this->escapeString($product_id),
                   'product_quantity' => $this->escapeString($product_quantity),
                   'product_price' => $this->escapeString($product_price),
                   'product_reseller_fee' => $this->escapeString($product_reseller_fee),
                   'product_reseller_poin' => $this->escapeString($product_reseller_poin),
                   'product_referral_fee' => $this->escapeString($product_referral_fee),
                   'product_referral_id' => $this->escapeString($product_referral_id),
                   'product_vendor_sales' => $this->escapeString($product_vendor_income),
                   'custom_invoice' => $this->escapeString($custom_invoice));

    $this->insert('sales_invoice', $data);
    $res = $this->getResult();
    return $res;
}
```

`$ongkir` variable result is `string(4) "6000"` when I do `var_dump`. so, I believe it's a string.

on the other side, I have a MySQL colum which has `Decimal` data type. when I tried to insert `$ongkir` into database, it ends up with zero.

do I have to convert this string into numeric data type? that's odd...

I tried to show on the screen what's the value of `$ongkir` :

```
$ongkir = $product->addInvoiceCopy ('ORD - 5762 5CF0 BFB9 6', null, '801', '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, '22000', null);
$total = (100 * 2) + $ongkir;
var_dump($total);
```

it produce :

```
int(6200)
```

so, `$ongkir` is not an empty variable or zero. but why I get zero when inserted into MySQL? any clue? thank you.

Comment: you should provide the SQL used for the insert

Comment: The data type of that column is `Decimal`, right? What did you set for the `Length/Values` field of that column (example is `40,2`)?

Comment: @LoganWayne : yes, it's decimal. decimal(13,2)

Comment: @HankyPanky : I used this : https://github.com/rorystandley/MySQL-CRUD-PHP-OOP to do connection with MySQL

Comment: This question simply is not clear enough. Not sufficient debugging info. You are all over the place with that variable. You are setting it to three things: a getResult, an array item, and then a sum.